# DataGrid pop up box when mouse over certain cells

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a Datagrid with say 5 Columns named as follows

RowID,
Name,
Age,
Height,
Image

What I want to do is when the mouse is over a cell in the Image Column, if there is an image there I want a pop up box to appear. I know I can just use a tool tip for the pop up but what's the best way of doing the check of is mouse over cell and does cell have an image present, if so then display popup.

EDIT:- Added code for DataGrid Column for Image Column

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">                        
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Source="{Binding IMG, Converter={StaticResource ImageConvert}}"/>                                           
        </DataTemplate>                            
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IsMouseOver` property to determine if the mouse is over an object, and a `MultiDataTrigger` to evaluate multiple conditions.

```
<Style TargetType="Image">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IMG, Converter={StaticResource IsImageNullConverter}}" Value="False" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- Your ToolTip here -->
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways. What I would recommend is to create a Template column type / style and implement this as a trigger when the mouse is within the cell.

Comment: Column is already created as a Template Column. How do I do the trigger part for mouse over cell?. Some cells may not have an Image present so it has to check first. I have edited first post to show xaml of the column.